# Program doesn't compile when "concept" defines a method with a parameter

Tags: nim-lang

I have a `concept` like this:

```
type Foo = concept x, y
  x.test(y) is bool
```

And then a type that tries to define a method that implements the `concept`:

```
type Bar = object
  s: string

proc test(x: Bar, y: string): bool =
  x.s == y
```

And a type that has a generic field `T: Foo` with a constructor that receives a `T: Foo`:

```
type Baz[T: Foo] = object
  f: T

proc make[T: Foo](f: T): auto =
  result = Baz[T](f: f)
```

When I create a new `Bar` and pass it to the `make` proc to make a new `Baz`, it doesn't compile:

```
let bar = Bar(s: "whatever")

let made = make[Bar](bar)
```

> Error: type mismatch: got (Bar) but expected 'T'

However it compiles if I drop the `y` in the concept, like `x.test is bool` and update the `test` proc accordingly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
type Foo = concept x, y
  x.test(y) is bool
```

To

```
type Foo = concept x
  x.test(string) is bool
```

In your code, it means x and y are both Foo type. If you really means that, please try this.

```
proc test(x: Bar, y: Bar): bool =
  x.s == y.s
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems I'm just not understanding concepts then. I'll take your info and give it another shot.